# Why does removing an unused `if` clause reduce execution time from 12ms to 4ms?

Tags: performance, rust

I'm using Rust to solve LeetCode [problem 645 "Set Mismatch"](https://leetcode.com/problems/set-mismatch/).

The solution is to iterate over the array and find the duplicate, then add an error to the duplicate to find the missing value.

Here's my code the first submission:

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn find_error_nums(nums: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
        let nums = &mut { nums };
        nums.sort();
        let mut dup = 0;
        for &num in nums.iter() {
            if dup == num {
                break;
            }
            dup = num;
        }
        let sum: i32 = nums.iter().sum();
        let correct_sum = ((1 + nums.len()) * nums.len() / 2) as i32;
        if sum < correct_sum {
            vec![dup, dup + correct_sum - sum]
        } else {
            vec![dup, dup - (sum - correct_sum)]
        }
    }
}
```

It cost 12ms. Then I noticed the `if` in the end was unnecessary, so I submitted a second time:

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn find_error_nums(nums: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
        let nums = &mut { nums };
        nums.sort();
        let mut dup = 0;
        for &num in nums.iter() {
            if dup == num {
                break;
            }
            dup = num;
        }
        let sum: i32 = nums.iter().sum();
        let correct_sum = ((1 + nums.len()) * nums.len() / 2) as i32;

        // the "if" changed to:
        let error = correct_sum - sum;
        vec![dup, dup + error]
    }
}
```

I did not expect to see any runtime difference, but, to my surprise, the second submission cost only 4ms!

Why does the trivial programming logic change make the execution time reduce 67%?

Comment: Are you testing with the compiler optimizations ? both source produces identical assembly https://godbolt.org/z/sE58FH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation profile matters in such cases. In `Debug` mode, the compiler does not work hard to optimize such kind of code.

If you compile your application in `Release` mode, these kind of things are optimized.

You can also specify your ***optimization level*** in a parameterized way in your config.

[Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-01-release-profiles.html)

---

I have reproduced your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in playground and you can see that it is pretty much giving the same time result in release mode since it is optimizing these kinds of branches in the code.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=feaac2c8a31b014357bc40a1d701e49e)